# How to use Datatable in javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
 $('#dFinalReport').html(_todayOrderLstHtml);
 $('#dFinalReport').dataTable(
  { "sDom": 'l<"floatR pLeft10"T><"floatR"f>rtip',
    "aaSorting": [[3, "asc"]], "iDisplayLength": 20
  });
```

How to use datatable in javascript?

i declared div element in html and called datatable using div id(dFinalReport).i got a error message --------->

DataTables warning (table id = 'dFinalReport'): Attempted to initialise DataTables on a node which is not a table: DIV

which id i should use to call datatable and when i call?

Comment: in javascript or in c#? Please edit either question or title.

Comment: "How to use" is not really a question. Do you get error? If not what are you trying to do?

Comment: When you ask a question, spend a little time to explauin what you want to do and where you get stuck. People are contributing their expert time to you, make it easy for them.

Comment: Please be more specific to get actual answer, here what you want either in Javacript or C# or combination of both....

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery.datatable plugin then please refer to.

http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and changing the wrapper fixed it for me. I don't know C# but check if you don't have something similar to this. I had the following in my code:

```
<div id='data_table_wrapper'>
{{=user_table}}
</div>
```

The "{{=user_table}}" basically calls the table - I am using python instead of C#. DataTable has a specific structure, the ID cannot be assigned to a DIV. Changing it to the following fixed my problem:

```
<table id='data_table_wrapper'>
{{=user_table}}
</table>
```

Edit: Also check the manual on http://www.datatables.net for further instructions - you have to be using a structure that includes thead, and so on..